# how Google drive playback video stream can play anywhere

Tags: video, stream, google-drive-api

i've been able method to generate video link from google drive like this

https://r14---sn-ab5l6n7z.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&id=76cfdbd2d7ae2010&itag=59&source=webdrive&app=explorer&ip=myip&ipbits=32&expire=1465290064&sparams=requiressl,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=AE1DA2322D2006DCCEA4DC6970C5D46B8D437DD7.9FEFC05A6ECB00C8FAA59ECCF5F0E4155EA60393&key=ck2&mm=31&mn=sn-ab5l6n7z&ms=au&mt=1465275331&mv=m&nh=IgpwcjAxLmxnYTA3KgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&pl=48&type=video/mp4;+codecs=\"avc1.42001E,+mp4a.40.2\"&quality=large

but why i can't play that that in production application ?

there is someone can help me ? or give me solution

thnks for your answer :)

Comment: "can't play" is not descriptive enough to troubleshoot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18479155/google-drive-video-streaming