# Google Drive Video Embedding in <video> not iframe

Tags: video, google-drive-api, streaming, video-streaming, playback

I've found this: [Google Drive - Video Streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18479155/google-drive-video-streaming)

and it works for files under 128MB, but for anything over it won't load. I was wondering how to do embedding like this: http://kissanime.to/Anime/Mirai-Nikki-TV/Episode-001?id=115968

Where the video link is:
https://r20---sn-ab5l6nel.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&id=ee6f2e039f1d6731&itag=22&source=webdrive&ttl=transient&app=texmex&ip=myipaddress&ipbits=32&expire=1471684009&sparams=expire,id,ip,ipbits,itag,mm,mn,ms,mv,nh,pl,requiressl,source,ttl&signature=7CAC58A44129044CAB15A5402C33DE8033A12B2A.83B3C79ED2B67525F0A2AD8EF6B9BD0C5EF04CA8&key=cms1&pl=15&sc=yes&cms_redirect=yes&mm=31&mn=sn-ab5l6nel&ms=au&mt=1471671868&mv=m&nh=IgpwcjAzLmxnYTA3KgkxMjcuMC4wLjE

The files are over 128MB, and the link is completely different, so how are they generating the googlevideo link?

I tried playing around with https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get but I couldn't get it to work, but that may just be me not being experienced enough, not sure.

Is there anywhere to find this information? I looked at the similar questions and none seem to have an answer.

To fully clarify, I'd like to embed Google Drive videos exactly like the kissanime link. It must be possible, because they're doing it, but there doesn't seem to be any information on it that I could find.

Thanks

Comment: Check this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331837/recover-video-url-through-google-drive-api-in-order-to-stream-the-video-in-an-ht), it seems similar to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Simple way to get the video link from Google Drive is passing Google Drive's url to GLD API.

Ex: `http://api.getlinkdrive.com/getlink?url=https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6VYU2mjTdy0WVRjb1BJUU1hYXM/view`